# How to get ip address, referer, and user agent in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ip-address, user-agent, referrer

I want to log user's ip address, referer, and user agent.
In PHP, I can get them from the following variables:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

How to get them in ruby?

Comment: PHP != Ruby. Without a web server, you won't have access to a web server environment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need the array [request.env](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/25-rails-request-environment-variables)

`request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']:`

Comment: Thanks. 
I tried google but i couldnt find them. 
About PHP, i always can easily find what i want to know with google. 
I think information about ruby is difficult to search.
Thanks for introducing the nice website!

Comment: can i use `request.env` in `just ruby` not in `ruby on rails`?

Comment: "can i use request.env in just ruby not in ruby on rails? " No, `request` won't exist as an object. Your best bet for simple exploration is the answer @Mark Thomas gave, or use Ruby's `CGI` library and write a simple CGI that will run under Apache or nginx.

Comment: @theTinMan I serched again with the keyword `cgi` you told me.
And i found i can get the information from `ENV['REMOTE_ADDR']`, `ENV['HTTP_REFERER']`, `ENV['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`.
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, those are standard environment settings defined by the HTTPd when calling your code as a CGI. If you're not familiar with that protocol it would be good to study up. It's the basis for all things web.

Answer (score 15):

PHP is embedded in a web server. Ruby is a general-purpose language: if you need a web server context, you'll have to install it yourself. Fortunately, it's easy.

One of the easiest ways to get started is with [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/). Install the gem:

```
gem install sinatra
```

Then create myapp.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
    request.user_agent
end
```

Start up the web server:

```
ruby -rubygems myapp.rb
```

Visit Sinatra's default URL: http://localhost:4567/

Et voilà.

Comment: thanks.
I dont know `sinatra` is installed to my server already.
Im not allowed to install anything to my server.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you by ruby you mean ruby on rails, the following link shows you how to access them:

http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/25-rails-request-environment-variables

Comment: thanks. but i meant ruby by ruby! im a beginner of ruby. and i just wanna make a simple logging program.