# What is the Ruby equivalent of PHP $_ENV?

Tags: php, ruby, cgi, environment-variables

I am writing a small CGI script in Ruby, which logs the data of visitors. I would like to log all CGI environment variables like REMOTE_ADDR, USER_AGENT, HTTP_REFERER etc. It was quite easy to iterate over the $_ENV array in PHP, and dump all the variables to examine them, but how can I do this in Ruby?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get ip address, referer, and user agent in ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701577/how-to-get-ip-address-referer-and-user-agent-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `ENV.inspect`

It seems to be a hash that holds what you are looking for.